# Searching for multiple search terms in documentDb

Tags: sql, substring, contains, azure-cosmosdb

I have a data structure in which I have tokenised an array of search terms.

```
{
   id: "some_id",
   name: "Bob's diner and eatery",
   searchTerms: ["bob", "bobs", "diner", "eatery"]
}
```

I can search for one term using the following query

```
SELECT VALUE 
    restaurant
FROM root 
    restaurant
JOIN 
    word 
IN 
    restaurant.searchTerms
WHERE 
    CONTAINS(word, @SearchTerm)
```

How would I go about searching where I have multiple search terms that I want to look for? Where there is more than one search term the document will only match if the search terms contains all of the search terms or parts of the search term. The following would match for example:

```
["bo", "eat"]
["bobs", "diner"]
```

But the following would not:

```
["bobs", "restaurant"]
```

As "restaurant" is not a matching search term.

Comment: Maybe not what you're looking for but this could easily be implemented in a Stored Procedure that runs server side

Comment: @JesseCarter please elaborate on this. I would not be against a stored procedure, please do another answer. If this is the only way to accomplish this at the moment I would be interested in seeing your approach.

Answer (score 4):

2 approaches:

**SQL Query**

If you are searching by full tokens in the array, you can `ARRAY_CONTAINS` and `OR` operator

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c, token1) OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(c, token2)
```

Here is an [example query](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo#Sandbox?SELECT%20*%0AFROM%20c%0AWHERE%20ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.tags,%20%7B%20name:%20%22babyfood%22%7D%20)%20OR%20ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.tags,%20%7B%20name:%20%22dessert%22%7D%20))

**Azure Search Indexer on top Azure Cosmos DB**

If you want to do rich full-text search (fuzzy text search, misspellings, etc.), you can add an Azure Search search indexer on top of your Azure Cosmos DB container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-documentdb

Comment: If you are searching for full tokens is there anyway to pass an array of strings as a parameter to search 'n' number of tokens or will I need to create n number of different queries (maybe up to 5 search terms)? What you are saying is that you cannot use the string contains function to search with an OR operator for multiple matches, are you sure about this?

Comment: The ARRAY_CONTAINS system function is essentially an equality match on an array of elements - and therefore can be run on the database index. The String CONTAINS system function is a substring match, and therefore cannot be optimized for index lookup within the collection. The only String function in this space that can be optimized for indexed retrieval is STARTS_WITH on a range index (where order is preserved). Be mindful that if there are no other predicates in the query filter other than a string CONTAINS, the query will require a scan and the RU cost will likely be high.

Comment: String CONTAINS technically will work, but may not be optimal if scanning through a large collection.

Comment: Something interesting about this approach that I have found is that ARRAY_CONTAINS actually does a substring match. I was pleasantly suprised when I searched for a substring and found it matched whole words.